# Add multiple headers in Astra (free) child theme Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header

I want to use different headers per page in my astra child theme. I have tried this code below in both page.php and my custom page-template.php but neither seems to work.

```
if (is_page(5196)) {
    get_header('custom');
} else {
    get_header();
}
wp_head();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your new header template for example header-custom.php

Lets say we want this header to be used in our page.php

```
get_header('custom');
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()): the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
get_footer();
```

Another approach which i prefer is using just header.php and inside load my template design

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
  <?php mytheme_header_template(); ?>
```

Add the following function in your functions.php

```
function mytheme_header_template() {
    //use any conditions
    if(is_page()):
    //create the following folder path in your theme - templates/header/header-template-one.php
    get_template_part('templates/header/header-template','one');
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both but none of them worked... It seems like nothing is happening? Can it be that it is different with the Astra theme? Astra also have <?php astra_head_bottom(); ?> function below wp_head() in head and <?php astra_schema_body(); ?>  before body__class();

Comment: Better contact the theme authors.